# Find highest product of natural numbers which sum to $S$?

Tags: number-theory

Given a number $S$, how can we find the highest $P$ such that there exist natural numbers $a$, $b$, & $c$

where $a + b + c = S$ and $a \times b \times c = P$?

Comment: I guess the answer is $\frac{S^{3}}{27}$

Comment: But it if and only if S derived by 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler problem, maximizing the product of two natural numbers whose sum is fixed, can be used to solve this (involving a product of three summands).

That is, in the case where two numbers have a (positive) fixed sum, their product is maximized by making them as nearly equal as possible.  Indeed, if $u+v = S$, then the maximum product $uv$ is obtained by taking $u = \lfloor S/2 \rfloor$ and $v = \lceil S/2 \rceil$.

Suppose that now $a+b+c = S$, where $a,b,c$ are natural numbers (zero included for the sake of simplicity).  Then should any pair of $a,b,c$ differ by more than one, we can increase the product $abc$ by adjusting that pair to be more nearly equal!  This leaves the sum fixed but increases the product (unless the product is forced to be zero because $S \lt 3$).

It follows that $abc$ is maximized (for fixed sum $a+b+c=S$) when no two of the summands differ by more than one.  Depending on the residue of $S$ mod $3$, this could mean:

(1) If $S \equiv 0 \bmod 3$, then take $a=b=c=S/3$.

(2) If $S \equiv 1 \bmod 3$, then take two of $a,b,c$ to be $\lfloor S/3 \rfloor$ and the third summand to be $\lceil S/3 \rceil$.

(3) If $S \equiv 2 \bmod 3$, then take two of $a,b,c$ to be $\lceil S/3 \rceil$ and the third summand to be $\lfloor S/3 \rfloor$.

Comment: +1 for the pattern of partial variation (https://books.google.com/books?id=-TWTcSa19jkC&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128&dq=pattern+of+partial+variation&source=bl&ots=Wt5UZ9ab5t&sig=LxGWdbwy-SMD0ywDQbSjAlsPvy0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4tPvMsoHKAhXKGh4KHdBPCbkQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=pattern%20of%20partial%20variation&f=false)